# Compile Java AWT project via command line

Tags: java, awt

I'm writing simple game in Java AWT. I can compile it and run via IntelliJ without problem. I encounter problem when I'm trying to compile it via cmd.

In my project i've got an image in `src/player.png`.

In `src/GUI/MyCanvas.java` I load it `player = ImageIO.read(new File("player.png"));`.

When i execute `javac Main.java -cp .` in `src/` it compile without problem but when i `java Main` it can not load image.

How should i compile it via cmd?

Answer (score 1):

Some ide's compile differently when handling files inside the jar. You should add a / behind player.png. Like so:

```
player = ImageIO.read(new File("/player.png"));
```

If the file is inside the jar you can try:

```
player = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../player.png"));
```

Comment: This not resolve my problem. I try `"/player.png"`, `"player.png"`, `"src/player.png"`, `"/src/player.png"` I always get exception `Can't read input file!`

Comment: Let me edit my answer as I have another idea of why it is not working.